# ChartJS AJAX Javascript

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an AJAX response that's delivering some data to a Javascript page.  I'm taking the original response and formatting it into individual arrays.

**Array 1 is**

```
["option1","option2","option3"]
```

**Array 2 is**

```
[ "["0.0","2.0","1.0","1.0","3.0"]","["1.0","2.0","11.0","11.0","12.0"]","["0.0","0.3","2.0","0.0","6.0"" ]
```

**Array 3 is**

```
["2019-01-07 05:00:00","2019-01-07 05:30:00","2019-01-07 06:00:00","2019-01-07 06:00:00","2019-01-07 06:30:00"]
```

I want to try and generate a chartjs line chart using this data with the caveat that there will often be more options in the first 2 arrays.

Array 3 on the X-Axis, Array 2 on the Y-Axis and Array 1 as the items in the legend and in the chart.

Can anyone suggest a starting point for this as I seem to be getting to a point where I can output the data but can't make the chart dynamic enough to get the data in?

There is an option of the first 2 arrays being combined in the JSON to form;

```
{
  "Labels": "option1",
  "Array": "["0.0","2.0","1.0","1.0","3.0"]"
},
{
  "Labels": "option2",
  "Array": "["1.0","2.0","11.0","11.0","12.0"]"
},
{
  "Labels": "option3",
  "Array": "["0.0","0.3","2.0","0.0","6.0"]"
}
```

There's no issue generating the charts if I know how many items will be in the original array but I need this to be dynamic - Although the date range will be static.

***EDIT***

Here's the Script I'm using to call the data at the moment;

```
function drawChart() {

  var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: 'includes/private/test6.php',
    dataType: 'json',
  }).done(function (results) {

    var label = []; 
    var array = [];

    results.forEach(function(data) {
      label.push(data.Label);
      array.push(data.Array);
      //console.log(data.Label);
    });

    var temp = {
      labels : label,
      datasets : [{
                    data: array
      }]
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
    var chart_vehicle = new Chart(ctx,temp);    
  });
}

drawChart();
```

console.log(data.Label) returns nothing in this example - My previous version was;

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'includes/private/test6.php',
  dataType: 'json',     
  success: function (data) {
      var label = [];
      var array = [];
    for(var i in data) {
    label[i] = data[i].Labels; 
    array[i] = data[i].Array; 
}

// used to correctly format the JSON
var names = label.slice(0, -1);  
var data = array.slice(0, -1); 

// Used to flip the array and return the first entry - Dates will always be the last thing returned.
var dates = JSON.parse(array.reverse(array)[0]); 

console.log(data);
console.log(names);
console.log(dates);
```

This correctly returns the data but I still can't get the data into a chart dynamically.

***Another EDIT***

I've made a few more changes and done a lot more reading.  Here's my fiddle containing my JSON response.  No chart is generated but I'm pretty sure the data should be correct!

https://jsfiddle.net/s04nye6h/7/

Comment: you wrote "Label" in your new code. but in your previous you wrote with "s" ->Lables . i think because that the console.log show nothing

Comment: Thanks for that... I still can't get the data to output correctly though.   https://jsfiddle.net/s04nye6h/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So I had to move your code upside down.

The JSON format and json type was wrong

As per ChartJs [this example](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/point-sizes.html) correct format for generating chart is this

```
var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'dataset - big points',
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ],
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                fill: false,
                borderDash: [5, 5],
                pointRadius: 15,
                pointHoverRadius: 10,
            }, {
                label: 'dataset - individual point sizes',
                data: [
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor(),
                    randomScalingFactor()
                ],
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                fill: false,
                borderDash: [5, 5],
                pointRadius: [2, 4, 6, 18, 0, 12, 20],
            },]
        }

    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
```

**issue 1:** What you were trying is this

```
var config = {
      type: 'line',
      labels: XXdates,
      datasets: []
    }
```

Notice the missing **data** attr

**issue 2:**  Data format has to be in Array of Number

```
eg: [  1,2,3,4,5]
```

but your data returns like this

```
"[ "1", "2" ,"0" ]"
```

**Solution :** Working Code after resolving above points

```
function drawChart() {

  var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/11poyc',
    dataType: 'json',
  }).done(function(results) {

    var label = [];
    var output = [];

    results.forEach(function(data) {
      label.push(data.Labels);
      output.push(data.Array);
    });

    var XXnames = label.slice(0, -1);
    var XXdata = output.slice(0, -1);

    var XXdates = JSON.parse(output.reverse(output)[0]);


        var data = {
            labels: XXdates,
        datasets: []
    }

    XXnames.forEach(function(XXa, i) {

        console.log(JSON.parse(XXdata[i]).map(Number));

      data.datasets.push({
        label: XXa,
        fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
        pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        data: JSON.parse(XXdata[i]).map(Number)
      });
    });

        var config = {
      type: 'line',
      data : data
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
  });
}

drawChart();
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s04nye6h/37/)

Comment: OMG!  Thank you so much for looking at this.  I'm actually quite happy with how close I got.  Knowing how to identify the problem is where my knowledge falls down!